# Shift characters in a string

Tags: string, character, shift

I am trying to shift characters 'n' times to the left or right in a string. Example would be "hello" shifted 3 to the right is "lohel". Another example is "hello" shifted 2 to the left would be "llohe".

So far i have this, but it only works for a shift 1 to the left:

```
strUserInput[0] = strUserInput[strUserInput.length()];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strUserInput.length(); i++){
        strUserInput[i] =  strUserInput[i + 1];
    }
```

Comment: shift to the left means appending the first character to the end of the string; shift to the right means appending the last character to the first of the list; and you can determine 'n' using loop.

Comment: what about the shifting of the rest of the characters in between the first and the last characters?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Timm_oh use substring to get the last char (or first char) and the rest of the string, and rearrange them.